# Need help why am I getting undefined here how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm getting undefined here. How can I load the data in `useEffect` and when everything is loaded how do I store it in `useState` variable and render things i need ?

```
const appDesign = require(`./data/${subcategory}`)

  useEffect(() => {if (router.asPath !== router.route) { }  }, [router])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not used the `next.js` before

But if you want to load something data by `useEffect()`, and store state in your component
declare a state var first

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
```

Then you should load the data and set state in useEffect's callback function
example:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  if (router) {
   // load some data or request api 
   // And set state
   let a = 1;
   setState(a);
  }
}, [router]);
```

more info please refer [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to load the data I'm a beginner and struggle a lot

Comment: where is your data come from ?  according to this line  
`const appDesign = require('./data/${subcategory}')`  the data should in the **data** folder at the same layer of your code